# Taxonomy term lookup during content migration is failing

Tags: migrations

I'm importing some data from a CSV file as nodes into my site. I'm having trouble with importing values into a entity reference field (which is a taxonomy term with multiple values).

Here's just that field (not going to write the entire migrations file as everything else but that field works)

```
  field_cars_available:
    - plugin: skip_on_empty
      source: "Audi, BMW, Citroen, Renault, Volvo"
      method: process
    - plugin: entity_lookup
      source: "Audi, BMW, Citroen, Renault, Volvo"
      value_key: name
      bundle_key: vid
      bundle: proposed_usage
      entity_type: taxonomy_term
      ignore_case: true
    - plugin: explode
      delimiter: ','
    - plugin: callback
      callable: trim
```

I've replaced the source file with the actual value for that field (so that it's more clear).
The only error I get is that the migration failed.

Any help?

Comment: did you use drush to show migration messages?

Comment: the delimiter needs an extra space ', '